# Jquery tab opening with condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to open tab 2 with condition. Tab 2 should be open on if selected checkbox more then one from tab 1 otherwise tab 2 will not open. How can i do it?

Script:
http://jsfiddle.net/mktgnp3e/694/

```
$("#tabs").tabs({

  beforeActivate: function(e, ui) {
  var id = $(ui.newPanel).attr('id');

  if(id=="tabs-2")

  if($('input[name="chk"]:checked').length > 1){
  alert("Tab 2 opened"); 

  }else{ 
   alert("Please select checkbox more then one in tab 1 otherwise tab 2 will not open");

  }  } }

   );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `$(this).tabs({ active: 0 });` inside your first condition in order to keep the first tab active, [here's](http://jsfiddle.net/mktgnp3e/712/) the updated example.

Comment: Thank you so much:)

Comment: Working perfectly

Comment: @AppleOrange since it's something different please open a new question, I'll take a look later!

Comment: Signo:Can you answer here?  this is very small question.

Answer (score 0):

try this:
    `$("#tabs").tabs({
        activate: function (e, ui) {
            var id = $(ui.newPanel).attr('id');
            if (id == "tabs-2") {
                if ($('input[name="chk"]:checked').length < 2) {
                    alert("Please select checkbox more then one in tab 1 otherwise tab 2 will not open");
                    $("#tabs").tabs("option", "active", 0);
                } else {
                    alert("Tab 2 opened");
                }
            }
        }
    });`

Comment: How to append html content on canvas?

Comment: have a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas